# Thymeleaf + Spring Boot + HTML + iterate through list in the list

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm very new to this Spring Boot + Thymeleaf. Apologies if the question is repeated but I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Here is some code samples:

```
public class PersonPOJO {
        private String uniqID;
        private List<AddressPOJO> addresses;
        // And Some other fields and setters and getters 
        private List<String> someList;
}

public class AddressPOJO {
        private String uniqAddId;
        private List<String> someList;
       // And Some other fields and setters and getters 
}
```

I'm omitting URL mapping and configuration annotation. Please bear with me.

```
public class ControllerClass {
         public String htmlLoadMethod(Model model) {
              // personsList is List<PersonPOJO>. I'm having them from global.
              model.addAttribute("persons", personsList);
              return "viewName";
         }
}
```

Now coming to my HTML page: Let's say 'viewName'

```html
<form action="#">
    <select required="required">
       <option th:each="person : ${persons}" th:value="${person.uniqID}" th:text="${person.uniqID}"></option>
    </select>
    <select>
        <!-- Load addresses (uniqAddIds) of the specific person I've selected in first select BOX -->
     </select>
   <select required="required">
        <!-- Load list of Strings of the specific addresses I've selected in addresses select BOX -->
   </select>
</form>
```

Here one more catch is, some times I do get the addresses list null in some PersonPOJOs. In that case address select BOX should be disabled. And someList of PersonPOJO should be loaded in third select BOX.

I hope you understand the problem. A simple code without JS will be appreciated more, but we can have JS functions if at all necessary. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok there are two way I can think of, but both would required some JS. The easiest way would be to send an Ajax request and fetch the address list. First, some modifications to your html, we need to add some ids to make it easier.

```
<form action="#">
    <select id="persons" required="required">
       <option th:each="person : ${persons}" th:value="${person.uniqID}" th:text="${person.uniqID}"></option>
    </select>
    <select id="addresses">
        <!-- Load addresses (uniqAddIds) of the specific person I've selected in first select BOX -->
     </select>
   <select required="required">
        <!-- Load list of Strings of the specific addresses I've selected in addresses select BOX -->
   </select>
</form>
```

Now you let's add a on change function to the **persons** select.

```
$('#persons').on('change', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/get-address',
        data: {personId: value},
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(address) {
            var addressList = $('$addresses');
            // Clear old data.
            addressList.empty();
            // Iterate through all the fetched addresses and append them.
            $.each(address, function() {
               addressList.append('<option value="'+address.uniqAddId +'"></option>');
            });
        }, error: function() {
            alert("Error loading the addresses.");
        }
    }) 
});
```

Now, you would need to add a new method in your controller that would look like this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get-addresses", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<Addresses> fetchAddresses(@RequestParam("personId") String personId) {
    // Fetch the addresses using the person's id.
    return addresses;    
}
```

The other way would be achieve using Thymeleaf fragments, but for your case, I believe it would be easier this way. Either way, both need JS. Hope it helps.